# Clickable href in QTextDocument (MS Windows platform)

Tags: qt, odt, qtextdocument

I am facing a strange behavior of Qt (**5.3.1**  - I  cannot use a newer version), when creating programmatically an *odt* file, I can add an href by doing:

```
QTextDocument* l_doc = new QTextDocument();
QTextCursor l_cursor(l_doc);

QTextCharFormat l_tc_fmt;
l_tc_fmt.setAnchor(true);
l_tc_fmt.setAnchorHref("www.stackoverflow.com");
l_tc_fmt.setForeground(QApplication::palette().color(QPalette::Link));
l_tc_fmt.setFontUnderline(true);

l_cursor.setCharFormat(l_tc_fmt);
l_cursor.insertText("stackoverflow");

QTextDocumentWriter l_twd("/home/test.odt");
l_twd.setFormat("odf");
l_twd.write(l_doc);
```

which results in an odt document containing a clickable string (works both on openoffice and msoffice):

[image]

The problem is that this works only on Linux platform, whereas on Windows I get the same underlined, blue string **but** it cannot be clicked  (neither in openoffice nor in msoffice).

Exporting the QTextDocument to html, the only difference I can see is as following:

- Windows
  [image]
- Linux
  [image]

Did anyone experienced the same problem on MS Windows?

Comment: Depends how you are viewing the file... If you are viewing it in a QTextBrowser for example you can connect to the 'anchorClicked(QUrl)' signal to detect when links are pressed. If you are unable to click it in Open Office / MS Office then perhaps opening the URL requires you to hold shift or ctrl when clicking it or something.

Comment: as already mentioned, when the odt file is made on Linux, the href works both on openoffice and msoffice (ctrl+click/shift+ctrl+click). When the odt file is made on Windows, it does not work (neither on Linux nor on windows)

Comment: You might need the href to be a full URL for it to work on Windows (i.e. https:// www. stackoverflow .com). Works for me using Libre Office on Windows.

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? Because on 5.3.1 it does not work even with full urls. And, what about hrefs to local files? No way.